# asp.net 4.5 ajax library $Find not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I recently upgraded from an older version of ASP.net (I believe 3.5) to 4.5. Now the ajax library method $find is not working in my javascript calls. I know the page has fully loaded before this occurs cause it's only on a user action that it calls the method.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var parObj = $find('<%= lkpInput.ClientID %>');
```

So as you can see I am using the ClientID property to be sure it's the right ID. After this call parObj is null. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you place $**find** inside **pageLoad** event, and try again?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) {
      var parObj = $find('<%= lkpInput.ClientID %>');
      console.log(parObj);
   }      
</script>
```